# Load Date() from FetchedRequest/Core Data into Date Picker SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, date, swiftui

Im loading CoreData into my View like this:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Rechnungen.entity(), sortDescriptors: []
)var rechnung: FetchedResults<Rechnungen>
```

Considering im only interested in one certain entity I applied this filter(Only shows a enity which has the right UUID)

```
ForEach(self.rechnung.filter{
        $0.id == rechnungoffen}) { rechnung in
```

This works fine since these TextFields show the correct outputs

```
Form {
        Section(header: Text("Rechnungsdetails")) {
            TextField("\(rechnung.verkaeufer)", text:$verkaeufer)
            TextField("\(rechnung.beschreibung)", text:$beschreibung)
```

And now I want to show the Date, and here's where Im stuck because this does not work, and I do not really know why

```
                DatePicker(selection: $datum, in: ...Date()){
                                Text("Datum & Uhrzeit")
                                    .onAppear{
                                        self.datum = rechnung.datum
                                    }
```

Doesn't the variable "datum"(Type Date(), also set as @State) should change to whatever rechnung.datum(Type Date()) is set to? and therefore display the date...

SwiftUI sadly still is documented poorly but maybe Im missing something essential here

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved the problem by myself, I changed the Picker code to:

```
DatePicker("Datum & Uhrzeit", selection: $datum, in: datum...Date())
                    .onAppear{
                        datum = rechnung.datum
                    }
```

which now works, god knows why!

Answer (score 1):

Change the picker code to:

```swift
DatePicker(selection: $datum, in: datum...Date()) {
    Text("Datum & Uhrzeit")
        .onAppear{
            self.datum = rechnung.datum
    }
}
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker